# Do you always need to specify the type of the return value in a function?

Tags: swift

I have a very simple question. Do you always need to declare the type of the returned value in a function (-> UIImage, or whatever)?

Why is it necessary to do so? What if in all the functions you wouldn't need to declare what is the type of the value that is returned?

Comment: You could just return `Any`, but that would defeat the purpose of static typing. You specify the return type to ensure type safety; that the object being returned will be compatible for what it's being used for.

Comment: How else would you know what the function returns?

Comment: Your question and use case are unclear.  Why on earth would you not want to know what type of object you are returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must always specify the return type unless the return type is `Void`.

It's necessary because Swift says it is required. It is a way to ensure the correct type is returned and the caller knows what type to expect. It's no different than declaring the type of any variable or function parameter.

It lets you catch many bugs at compile time and it avoids a lot of potential runtime issues.